# Como estruturar um projeto PHP para multi ecommerces trabalhando com o mesmo crm

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso desenvolver 5 lojas virtuais em hospedagens diferentes, onde todas vão ser administradas por uma hospedagem x.

H2,H3,H4,H5,H6 -> (H1)
Na hospedagem H1 ficará o painel CRM, onde será feita a impressão de pedidos, cadastro de produtos e etc.

Todas as hospedagem vão trabalhar com o mesmo banco de dado, onde terá as configurações de cada loja, ao cadastrar um produto ou edita-lo será possível determinar em quais lojas ele estará disponível.

**Até aqui tudo certo, o problema esta nas imagens dos produtos, a melhor opção seria exibir as imagens apontando para a H1 ou fazer o upload manual de cada produto em suja respectiva hospedagem?**

**Sobre a ideia da estrutura do projeto em trabalhar em hospedagens diferentes, é uma boa ideia?**

Comment: É necessário mais informações para ajudar: estas lojas são todas administradas pela mesma equipe (usuários)? Quando você diz "hospedagem" está falando de uma única instalação do sistema ou do servidor, ou ainda dos endereços URL ? Você vai desenvolver o sistema ou é um CRM/E-Commerce de mercado? Se for você, tem o modelo do banco de dados, como resolveu os relacionamentos dos dados de cada loja com seus produtos? A imagem eu acredito seja uma consequência de todas estas decisões anteriores estarem definidas e modeladas.

Comment: Certo.
Estou fazendo o desenvolvimento das lojas para uso próprio.

Tenho um plano locaweb onde o mais viável é criar sites (hospedagens diferentes, onde em cada hospedagem administro seu domínio e emails respectivos)
Ex
CRM.lojaMAIN.com.br
lojaMAIN.com.br
LojaGospel.com.br
LojaGamers.com.br
LojaCountry.com.br
LojaFitness.com.br

Essas lojas serão administradas por min no crm.lojaMain..., criei uma tabela para lojas onde fica o id da loja e sua configurações, na tabela produtos tem o campo store (varchar255) onde em cada loja é feito uma busca através de um like=store em cada loja

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acordo com sua resposta para minha pergunta, vou responder então à questão específica

> a melhor opção seria exibir as imagens apontando para a H1 ou fazer o upload manual de cada produto em suja respectiva hospedagem?

Se os produtos são únicos por loja, digo, não vai vender o mesmo produto em todas as lojas, o ideal é associar o id da loja como uma chave estrangeira no produto. Quanto à subir as imagens por loja, se toda a base das lojas é única para elas, então fará o upload no mesmo local, visto que a lógica da sua aplicação identificará o produto e irá carregar a imagem correta do disco.

Porém, acredito que você esteja com alguns problemas maiores de modelagem do seu banco de dados, quando fala

> na tabela produtos tem o campo store (varchar255) onde em cada loja é feito uma busca através de um like=store em cada loja

Me parece que não compreendeu como é feito o relacionamento entre tabelas de um banco de dados relacional, usando chaves primárias ou estrangeiras.

Aconselho estudar sobre MER (Modelo Entidade Relacionamento).

**Complementando** minha resposta com uma explicação sobre o por quê evitar varchar para chaves primárias e estrangeiras: se o id de sua loja é numérico, o ideal é trabalhar com campos numéricos, campos de tipo que aceitam caracteres para este fim são menos performáticos. Se falarmos exclusivamente do tipo varchar, ele tem o problema de não ser indexável na maioria dos gerenciadores de bancos de dados, então sua aplicação terá muita degradação de performance, principalmente nos momentos de join dos relacionamentos das queries.

Comment: Alguns produtos estarão disponíveis em mais de uma loja, vou explicar melhor prq trabalhar todas as lojas no mesmo banco:

alguns produtos serão por encomenda, ex:
camiseta da flor rosa, (ela será retirada de um estoque de camisetas lisas ) onde nas outras lojas tbm terão prod que serão retirados do estoque únicos de pçs sem estampas.

o objetivo é que toda administração, impressão de pedidos, controle de estoque seja feito em um único local, sem precisar ficar entrando em cada loja para gerenciar, todos pedidos saíram com infos de produção da loja main e distribuído por loja respectiva.

Comment: Ok, quanto à questão de se vale a pena uma única base de sistema para este contexto, sim vale. Para resolver os relacionamentos múltiplos use uma tabela intermediária, por exemplo: produto -> loja_produto <- loja ... onde loja_produto contem o id de loja e de produto, assim você tem um relacionamento n para n coberto. O estoque se é global, pode ser um campo em produto. Mas mantenho minha resposta acima, acho realmente necessário que você estude Modelagem de Banco de Dados para conseguir acertar na solução

Comment: Certo vou dar uma pesquisada agora mesmo.

Comment: Eu novamente, entendi que como estou trabalhando com o tipo N:N o ideal é criar uma tabela como vc disse para ligar a tabela produtos a tabela loja certo?

Trabalhando com um campo varchar no produto e utilizando loja1id, loja2id, etc... tem qual desvantagem? Apenas gostaria de saber por curiosidade de conhecimentos mesmo.

Comment: se o id de sua loja é numérico, o ideal é trabalhar com campos numéricos, campos de tipo que aceitam caracteres para este fim são menos performáticos. Se falarmos exclusivamente do tipo varchar, ele tem o problema de não ser indexável na maioria dos gerenciadores de bancos de dados, então sua aplicação terá muita degradação de performance, principalmente nos momentos de join dos relacionamentos das queries